# SEDE counting tag score is way off

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I wanted to see where I ranked in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) on StackOverflow, so I wrote a SEDE query for that:

```
select row_number() over(order by Score desc),
  *
from
(SELECT TOP 5
    Posts.OwnerUserId,
    Users.DisplayName,
    SUM(case when VoteTypeId = 2 then 1 else -1 end) as Score
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId in (2,3)
    INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
WHERE 
    Tags.TagName = 'c++'
    AND Posts.PostTypeId = 2
GROUP BY Posts.OwnerUserId, Users.DisplayName
ORDER BY Score DESC) as T
```

which yields the top users as:

```
+====+=============+========================+=======+
+    | OwnerUserId | DisplayName            | Score |
+====+=============+========================+=======+
|  1 |       34509 | Johannes Schaub - litb | 29980 |
|  2 |      922184 | Mystical               | 29701 |
|  3 |      596781 | Kerrek SB              | 21860 |
|  4 |      179910 | Jerry Coffin           | 21088 |
|  5 |      204847 | Mike Seymour           | 19717 |
+====+=============+========================+=======+
```

But if I took at the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers) link, while Mystical is at 29.7k, Kerrek at 21.9k, Jerry at 21k, and Mike at 19.7k... Johannes there shows up at 25.1k... nearly 5000 lower. Most users I have exactly right... except Johannes.

Similarly, for [java](/questions/tagged/java), I get BalusC at 60,047 where the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) link has 55.7k.

Where do these large differences come from for some users? What am I overcounting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query also includes the score for Community Wiki answers, whereas in the top users (answerers) — as well as tag badge-progress — Community Wiki answers are excluded (see the bottom of the top users page). Note that [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A34509+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+wiki%3Ayes+is%3Aanswer) has some very high scoring Community Wiki answers in the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, and similarly [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+%5Bjava%5D+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3Ayes) in the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag.

Include `Posts.CommunityOwnedDate Is NULL` is the `WHERE` clause, and this should get things closer to the real values. (I say closer since the SEDE data is only updated weekly, and so there will still be discrepancies.)